# What are the mathematical foundations of the renormalisation group?

Tags: integration, reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

Briefly, RG refers to mathematical tools that allows systematic investigation of the changes of a physical system as viewed at different distance scales. These methods are very important in quantum field theory and statistical mechanics. I'm currently taking a statistical physics course so I'm very curious about this.

[Sarada Rajeev](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/people/faculty/rajeev_sarada/), a physicist at the University of Rochester, says that 'a new integral calculus of functions of an infinite number of variables is needed' in order to give these methods a rigorous mathematical foundation.

**Update**: In a correspondence where I was discussing how this would be different from variational calculus, I got the following reply from Professor Rajeev,

> Variational calculus is the differential calculus of an infinite
>   number of variables: paths. The corresponding integral calculus is the
>   "path integral" one pioneered by Weiner and Feynman. Although we have
>   the theory of integration over paths ( the space of functions of one
>   variable  (good enough for Stochastic ODEs and Quantum Mechanics) we
>   do not have it for for fields (functions of several variables).
>   Renormalization theory gives us hints on when such a theory is likely
>   to exist. Constructing it would be at least as important as the
>   discovery of Lebesgue integration.

This statement by professor Rajeev is very interesting as it highlights the importance of such mathematical foundations(to him and many other mathematical physicists).

Comment: @user8268 Good idea. I'll do that in a minute.

Comment: Surely all kind of fixed point theorems are important to analyse the direction of flow and the (meta)stable points of the Gell-Mann-Low equations. this said, the theory of RG in general is a theory of non-linear , coupled differential equations

Comment: @tired It appears that Martin Hairer is contributing to its foundations: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5113v4.pdf

Comment: I wrote an answer to a similar question on MathOverflow. See <a href="http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62770/what-mathematical-treatment-is-there-on-the-renormalization-group-flow-in-a-spac">this post</a>.